# Which of the following are Subrings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let    $R'=M_{2}(R)$, which of the following are subrings?

A.- The Set: 
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{bmatrix} $a,b,c\in R$, of upper triangular matrices.

B.- The Set:
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&-a\end{bmatrix} $a,b,c\in R$, of matrices with trace $0$.

so far I've let $a\in R\setminus \{0\}$, and consider the set $aR = \{ar: r\in R\}$. Using a lemma shown that $|aR| = R$, and deduced that there exists $r\in R$ such that $ar = 1$.

Comment: What did you try? There are some conditions you need to check. What goes wrong when you try to check these?

Comment: Do subrings have to contain $1$ ?

Comment: In the case $B$ take $a=1, b=c=0$ and denote this matrix by $A$  show that the product $AA = Id$ and $Id$ isn't of this form.

Comment: Yes i see your point @ReinaldoR. how would you go about A?

Comment: The case $A$ is, in fact, a subring, you've to check those properties to be a ring...